# Existing microwave trapped ion quantum computer?

Tags: quantum-computer, microwaves

In the recent paper [*Blueprint for a microwave trapped ion quantum computer*](http://advances.sciencemag.org/content/3/2/e1601540), the authors envision a scalable design for a quantum computer, built from smaller ones implemented on silicon wafers, "using ion transport on microfabricated trap arrays to realize an ion trap quantum computer" (which they credit to others). There's a nice animation one link away from [there](http://advances.sciencemag.org/content/suppl/2017/01/30/3.2.e1601540.DC1) .

I wonder to what degree that technology exists and has been used to make a working quantum computer transporting individual ions carrying the quantum information from one location to the other, as depicted (even on a small scale, e.g. a single small IC). How many qbits or locations have been achieved? What kind of computation has been performed?

Comment: Those authors are generally at the bleeding edge of trapped-ion quantum computing, so their latest papers is a good place to look for the state of the art. Despite how easy the video makes it seem, the X junctions are very challenging to implement - you can shuttle ions around relatively easily, but making them turn corners without messing up the internal quantum state was much more difficult than anticipated, though I get the impression that this is a relatively solved challenge at least for a single junction.